# Mvvmcross MVXView within a ViewController binding

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind a property of an MvxView that is contained in a View, but the binding doesn't seem to work.

The MvxView :

```
[Register("UIWeek")]
public partial class UIWeek : MvxView
```

[Picture of the View Containing UIWeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BOyF.png)

The property I am trying to bind in UIWeek:

```
public DateTime SelectedDate
{
  get
  {
    return _selectedDate;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_selectedDate != value)
    {
      DateTime oldSelectedDate = _selectedDate;
      _selectedDate = value;
      _dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(() => RaiseSelectedDateChanged(_selectedDate, oldSelectedDate));
    }
  }
}
```

The binding in the view controller :

```
set.Bind(InvoiceDateWeekView).For(v => v.SelectedDate).To(vm => vm.InvoiceDate);
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What does not work? Is it working partially? This should potentially work OneWay, so your setter should be hit if your binding is correct.

Comment: I've used data binding on the View/Platform side a lot, so I know it works. It's hard to tell from your code snippets, but did you remember to call `set.Apply()` to initiate the bindings?